# What is your definition for neighborhood in topology?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

As you know, Munkres-Topology and Rudin-Analysis are really widely using textbooks for undergraduates. They all define a 'neighborhood of $x$' as an open set containing $x$, so i have followed this definition for 6 months. However, surprisingly, Wikipedia defines a 'neighborhood of $x$' as a set containing an open set containing $x$.

This really makes me annoyed, since this means that whenever I find a definition referring to a neighborhood on Wikipedia, I have to check whether that definition is equivalent to my definition of a neighborhood.

Which one is widely used?

Comment: I would never put a Wikipedia definition over the definition of any widely used textbook

Comment: Same here, but I have to say I never used Rudin nor Munkres, and whenever I read a definition of a "neighbourhood" of some point $x\in X$, it was a set $V\subseteq X$ with $p\in V$ containing an open subset $U\subseteq X$ with $p\in U$. But then again, in my experience you nearly always read "Let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $x$", since one can usually restrict to such and show the desired stuff there.

Comment: This seems to be essentially the same question as http://math.stackexchange.com/q/80025/

Comment: I think I've seen (don't recall where) "open/closed neighborhood" when I'm specifically dealing with metric spaces, where I take it to mean "open/closed $\varepsilon$-ball." Maybe that's the sort of thing Wikipedia is referring to?

Comment: There are advantages to both definitions. For example one might like to say that a space is locally compact if for every neighbourhood of a point contains a compact neighbourhood... but compact subsets are usually not open!

Comment: @Zhen I'm completely unfamiliar with the definition in wikipedia. Does the existence of a neighborhood (wikipedia definition) of $x$ gurantees the the existence of a open set containing $x$ then?

Comment: @Leon, Rand: really? I consider  the average Wikipedia article much, much better than the "widely used textbook" of, say, Stewart. Do you realize that people like Terry Tao and other luminaries regularly contribute and refer to Wikipedia?

Comment: It makes no sense to me to define a neighbourhood as an open set. How will we then define regular topological spaces (has a closed neighbourhood base)? and locally compact spaces (has a compact neighbourhood base)?

Comment: @Rabee: There is obviously no problem defining either *regular* or *locally compact* even if one uses the narrow definition of *neighborhood*. Indeed, I first learned both concepts from a text that did not use the term *neighborhood* at all.

Comment: I don't know who Munkres is, but I looked in some reputable topology books (by Kelley and Willard) and they define a neighborhood of a point $x$ as a set which contains an open set which contains $x.$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From mathworld@wolfram:

> In a topological space, an open neighborhood of a point is an open
>   set containing it. A set containing an open neighborhood is simply
>   called a neighborhood.

In most cases proofs involve open neighborhoods, so it usually shouldn't make too much of a difference, but It does look like different text books define this differently.

Comment: Would you please answer my comment above?

Comment: @Katlus - Of course it guarantees it. by definition, if a neighborhood (wiki def) exists it contains an open set which in turn contains the point.

Answer (score 10):

Rudin's *Real and complex analysis*, third edition (1987), page 9 of the French translation (1998):

> Définissons d'abord un *voisinage* d'un point $x$ comme un ensemble contenant un ouvert contenant le point $x$. (*Let us first define a* neighborhood *of a point $x$ as a set containing an open set containing the point $x$.*)

It appears (thanks to @Martin for this) that the English and the French versions disagree since, on page 9 of the third English edition there is a parenthetical remark defining neighborhoods:

> (A neighborhood of a point x is, by definition, an open set which contains x.)

This decision of the French translator of Rudin's book to modify this definition backfires on him, later on in the book, on page 35-36 Definition 2.3(d): there, the English text defines again a neighborhood as open and mentions parenthetically that some authors use the other definition; and all of this is translated faithfully in the French edition, in contradiction with the choice made earlier on to modify Rudin's text. *Traduttore, traditore*...

Munkres's *Topology*, second edition (2000), indeed stipulates that every neigborhood is open and, immediately after the definition, signals the alternative definition (pages 96-97).

All in all, it seems that readers of Rudin's and Munkres's books might not be completely taken aback by Wikipedia's version since both these authors, while following the other convention, explicitly mention this one.

Comment: The English and the French versions seem to disagree on that point. On page 9 of the third English edition there is a parenthetical remark defining neighborhoods: *(A neighborhood of a point $x$ is, by definition, an open set which contains
$x$.)*

Comment: @Martin Indeed. Thanks for your remark, see edited answer.

Comment: +1 for the nice addition on backfiring and especially for the last sentence of your post.

Comment: A very good point about Munkres' second edition-this clearly signals the OP was probably using the first edition.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question asks "What is your definition?" I'll say that my book [Topology and Groupoids](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/topgpds.html) (first edition, "Elements of Modern Topology" (1968)) uses the definition that a neighbourhood $N$ of $x$ is such that $x$ is contained in the interior of $N$. Thus in the real line, $[0,1]$ is a neighbourhood of all of its points except $0,1$.

In practical terms, the difference between the two definitions is marginal, except that the neighbourhood axioms seem simpler with  the more general definition.

I still hold to the idea that *for a beginner*, the definition of a topology in terms of neighbourhoods is the most intuitive and easily motivated; thus for continuity it is related to $\varepsilon-\delta$ methods in analysis. Of course students have to become familiar with the open set definition as well, including that for continuity, but should not have the idea imposed  that there is only one route to the useful concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer the definition of it being a set that contains an open set that contains the element. When people say that a neighbourhood of $a \in X$ is just an open set that contains the element a, it takes off some cases. I'll explain it better:

We say that a is an *interior* point of $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ when there is a number $\epsilon>0$ such that the open interval $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ is a subset of $X$.

The set of the interior points of $X$ is called the *interior* of the set $X$, represented by $int\space X$.

When $a\in int\space X$, we say that $X$ is a *neighbourhood* of the point a.

A set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is called an *open set* when $A = int \space A$, that is, when all the points in A are interior to A.

Being so, when a 'neighbourhood of $x$' is defined as being an open set containing $x$, it is not considering the cases in which the set in which $x$ belongs is a closed set. 
Let's say that we have $c<x<d$ and $x \in A = [c,d]$. Then the interior of $A$ is the open set $int \space A = (c,d)$. Also, we have that $x \in int \space A$, and so $A$ is a neighbourhood of the point $x$ - it is a set containing an open set that contains the element $x$.

In the spectrum of topological spaces, one talks about open and closed neighbourhoods - in that case, the definition of an '*open* neighborhood' can *then* be stated as an open set containing the element.